# Android WebView: use firefox/gecko browser engine on Lineage OS

Tags: android, android-webview, lineageos

On Lineage OS (and maybe on any Android?), it is possible to change the default WebView render (which is set by default to `AOSP Browser`, the default android browser without GAPPS). When I install Chrome (even without GAPPS installed), I can change this default to `Chrome` in the Setting/Development (which is practical in my case as the default browser has some annoying bugs).

Is it possible to also use Firefox's engine instead of Browser/Chrome (I don't want to have chrome installed and rely on proprietary software)? Installing Firefox (Fennec on FDroid) is not enough.

Thanks!

Comment: also in lineage developers options there is a setting that I do not understand. the next one "Webview Simultaneous Processing" "Run WebView renderer separately" :  I never understanded what this setting is for, but I noticed that if I turn it off, and I  uninstall the webview, the webview keeps working on my phone. As if it whould be there. A example is the app Etar, or the Email program K-9. If I turn off the  "Run WebView renderer separately" and after this uninstall the webview App and the HTML renderer thesse two apps continue to render html content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible because GeckoView does not implement the WebView API according to one of the authors.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckoview/issues/167#issuecomment-902022285

Comment: Thanks. As I understand, this is even a legal issue?

Comment: @tobiasBora That would be the most ironic legal issue in history. Google to Oracle for more than a decade with 8 billion dollars in damages being claimed: "*no no, you see, APIs can't be copyrighted, we can just take the Java language and do what we please!*" and then turn around and tell Mozilla: "*How could you do this to us, make an implementation for **our** WebView API‽*"

Comment: However, they can restrict what you can ship as a vendor. "Oh you want the Googly maps and the Youtube? Hah, thou shallt not [give the user access to their system by default](https://forum.fairphone.com/t/fairphone-s-approach-to-root-on-the-fairphone-2/11893) nor ship with any WebView other than Chrome! Let it be so!" and somehow it is not an [antitrust issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Competition_law&oldid=1029333464#Dominance_and_monopoly) to use this dominance in web applications to enforce which software their users can install on *their* devices \`\\_(:|)_/\`

Answer (score 2):

Besides the common Chrome `WebView`, there's also Mozilla [GeckoView](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/).

The [quick start](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/consumer/docs/geckoview-quick-start) shows how it can be added - and there's also an [example app](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/geckoview_example).

The down-side is, that [geckoview-70.0.20191022130254.aar](https://maven.mozilla.org/?prefix=maven2/org/mozilla/geckoview/geckoview/70.0.20191022130254/geckoview-70.0.20191022130254.aar) has 149.8 MB.

This would be it's [API documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/index.html) and it's home on [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/geckoview).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I understand GeckoView correctly, it is made to create new apps, not to replace the default WebView used by all android apps.

Comment: Of course this has more overhead, because there is no system/library WebKit engine used, but it is generally what you were asking for. With Chrome WebView, there is a package installed, but GeckoView needs that library dependency instead. The API docs clearly show what it is ...

Comment: So when the `GeckView` is availible as simple `View`, why can't you implement a `WebView` as a `GeckoView`?

Comment: @FiliusPatris [org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/index.html) can be used instead of [android.webkit.WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView). The one has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: @MartinZeitler so why hasn't sombody extended `WebView` and delegated the implementation to `GeckoView`? Where is the problem?